# Rails 5 Action Cable deployment with Nginx, Puma & Redis

Tags: nginx, puma, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to deploy an Action Cable -enabled-application to a VPS using Capistrano. I am using Puma, Nginx, and Redis (for Cable). After a couple hurdles, I was able to get it working in a local developement environment. I'm using the default in-process /cable URL. But, when I try deploying it to the VPS, I keep getting these two errors in the JS-log:

```
Establishing connection to host ws://{server-ip}/cable failed.
Connection to host ws://{server-ip}/cable was interrupted while loading the page.
```

And in my app-specific `nginx.error.log` I'm getting these messages:

```
2016/03/10 16:40:34 [info] 14473#0: *22 client 90.27.197.34 closed keepalive connection
```

Turning on `ActionCable.startDebugging()` in the JS-prompt shows nothing of interest. Just ConnectionMonitor trying to reopen the connection indefinitely. I'm also getting a load of 301: Moved permanently -requests for /cable in my network monitor.

#### Things I've tried:

- Using the `async` adapter instead of Redis. (This is what is used in the developement env)
- Adding something like this to my `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/{app-name}`:

  ```
  location /cable/ {
    proxy_pass http://puma;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
  }
  ```
- Setting `Rails.application.config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins` to the proper host (tried "http://{server-ip}" and "ws://{server-ip}")
- Turning on `Rails.application.config.action_cable.disable_request_forgery_protection`

No luck. What is causing the issue?

```
$ rails -v
Rails 5.0.0.beta3
```

Please inform me of any additional details that may be useful.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Finally, I got it working! I've been trying various things for about a week...

The 301-redirects were caused by nginx actually trying to redirect the browser to /cable/ instead of /cable. This is because I had specified /cable/ instead of /cable in the `location` stanza! I got the idea from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25502657/3719597).